# Определить размер картинки в байтах, которая хранится в QImage

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

Есть функция, нужно после конвертации картинки определить размер файла в байтах. Далее размер передаётся в функцию, откуда возвращается строка, и вставляется в label. Пример строки "Размер изображения составляет : 5 мегабайт 500 килобайт 777 байт".
Саму функцию конвертации привожу:

```
 void  convertImage()
 {
   imageJpeg = imageBMP;

   QByteArray byteArrayImage;
   QBuffer buffer(&byteArrayImage);
   buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
   imageJpeg.save(&buffer, "jpg");

    //  
    //  Тут определяем сколько весит изображение imageJpg в байтах
    //   ui->label->setText("тут строку с выводом мб,кб, байтах)

   }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Поскольку после конвертации все байты изображения записываются в `byteArrayImage`, можно взять размер следующим образом:

```
int imgSizeBytes = byteArrayImage.size();
```

[`QByteArray::size()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#size)

Comment: То, что нужно!) Спасибо.